# Discrepancy in result when calculating time using decimal(10,1)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have query that returns total seconds as **28943** , I am using below query to convert seconds

````
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
  userID int,
  uDateTime datetime,
  totalsec bigint
)
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable VALUES (123, getdate(),1503);
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable VALUES (123, getdate(),893);
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable VALUES (123, getdate(),14524);
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable VALUES (123, getdate(),6631);
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable VALUES (123, getdate(),13);
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable VALUES (123, getdate(),889);
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable VALUES (123, getdate(),4490);
GO
SELECT  userid,Format( SUM(CAST((CAST(totalsec as float) / 3600)as decimal(10,1))) ,'N1')
FROM dbo.MyTable
group by userid,cast(udatetime as date)

```

Output :  1,'07/07/2021',7.8

When I am running below query 
```
SELECT
    FORMAT(SUM(CAST((CAST(28943 AS float) / 3600) AS decimal(10, 1))), 'N1')
```

Output : 8.0
````

I was wondering why there is this discrepancy in output?

Comment: Your examples are mixed up. `28943 / 3600` results in `8.03972222222222` not `7.6`. And the reason you are getting `8` rather than `8.04` is because `decimal(10,1)` doesn't have enough decimal places. And neither does your `format`, `N1` is only 1dp.

Comment: Move `SUM()` to inside the expression, as in `...SUM((TotalSec)...`.

Comment: thanks  moving sum inside worked CAST(SUM(CAST(ttlSecs as float) / 3600)as decimal(10,1)).

Comment: I  am using decimal(10,1) because I need only one digit after decimal
I need 8.0 instead of 8.04

Comment: You were already getting 8.0? None of the data you provided gave 7.6. You also benefit from casting 3600 to a float. Assuming you really need floats, they are a bit unpredictable in how they work. Mostly one wants decimal.

Comment: @DaleK floats are perfectly predictable if you work in binary math. They are only classed as non-deterministic because different CPUs work them slightly differently. The IEEE rules are quite clear though, and a base2 fraction can always be represented exactly

Comment: @Charlieface sure if you understand how they work - but many people use them and expect them to store an exact number - and are surprised when they do not. Hence I like to check that people are using them intentionally rather than accidentally.

Comment: Now I understand why I am getting 7.8 please look at the example

Answer (score 0):

The first query get its data from a table were you sum up values that you have cut if with decimal(10,1)

In the secound query you already inserted the sum. The sum function doesn't do anything without a table as source.

Hence you have different results because you calculated with different values.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why I am getting 7.8 .
below query solved the issue
SELECT  userid,Format( CAST(SUM(CAST(totalsec as float) / 3600)as decimal(10,1)) ,'N1')
FROM dbo.MyTable
group by userid,cast(udatetime as date)